# Query which would return non common empId from both the tables

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables `Employee` and `EmployeeAddress`. I want to have a query which would return non common `empId` from both the tables.

Structure of the tables.

- `Employee` : EmpID and EmpName
- `EmployeeAddress` : EmpID and Address

Answer (score 2):

Combination of `NOT IN` and `UNION` should do

```
select empid
from employee
where empid not in (select empid from EmployeeAddress)
union select empid
from EmployeeAddress
where empid not in (select empid from employee)
```

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to use `FULL OUTER JOIN`

```
SELECT COALESCE(e.EmpID, ea.EmpID) AS EmpID
FROM   Employee e
       FULL OUTER JOIN EmployeeAddress ea
         ON e.EmpID = ea.EmpID
WHERE  e.EmpID IS NULL
        OR ea.EmpID IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select * FROM (select empid from employee Except select empid from EmployeeAddress )A
UNION 
SELECT * FROM (select empid from EmployeeAddress Except select empid from employee)B
```